# How can I create and delete files in an NTFS partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, mount, ntfs

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 18.10.

I have 6 NTFS partitions And I want to get all access to those drives.
I cannot paste, create or delete anything from those drives. 
Is it possible? If it is possible, how?

My `fstab` description is

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=dc354829-f570-432c-8dbc-b5f64d498e1d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=aee32533-8486-402b-9e64-7970f429e12d /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=fd8aab6e-8423-421e-a33b-590b15938c06 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

and `blkid` is:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="04CE3588CE357352" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="305a33dd-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows" UUID="E0FE39DFFE39AF22" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="305a33dd-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="180276320276154A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="305a33dd-03"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="System File {Don't Open it pls}" UUID="01D362CEDE257C60" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e3d2bf96-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="01D362CEE07E1260" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e3d2bf96-02"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="TV Serise" UUID="01D368208E4E61A0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e3d2bf96-03"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="fd8aab6e-8423-421e-a33b-590b15938c06" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="e3d2bf96-05"
/dev/sdb6: UUID="dc354829-f570-432c-8dbc-b5f64d498e1d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e3d2bf96-06"
/dev/sdb7: UUID="aee32533-8486-402b-9e64-7970f429e12d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e3d2bf96-07"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="305C47EF5C47AF02" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5a6c94e8-01"
/dev/sdc2: LABEL="2 software" UUID="719487CC26DAD33E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5a6c94e8-02"
/dev/sdc3: LABEL="3" UUID="A6AEB439AEB40439" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5a6c94e8-03"
/dev/sdc4: LABEL="Movie" UUID="0A8B231E3AED0A2E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="5a6c94e8-04"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Comment: If the NTFS partitions are in a 'hibernated' state, they are opened in *read only* state for safety purposes (windows 10 fast boot is really a hibernate, with an unsafe/unclosed file system allowing faster-booting as it restores the fs cache from a saved area not the file system itself). I would add entries in your `/etc/fstab` for your file-systems, but also check they are 'clean' & 'complete' (ie. all data is written to them & not part in a quick-boot cache outside of file-system)

Comment: pls add entries in fstab for me. It will be a great help for me.

Answer (score 3):

NTFS has been something a lot of people have had issues with, and as such there are a lot of questions already about this topic.

This is a permission issue, where your user do not have permission to write to these partitions/drives.

Please have a look at these:

- [Can't write to NTFS formatted drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93109/cant-write-to-ntfs-formatted-drives)
- [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/)
- [Can't mount NTFS partition with write permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857089/cant-mount-ntfs-partition-with-write-permissions)
- [Setting permission for NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223016/setting-permission-for-ntfs-partition)

Comment: Thanks  man. I appretiate it. Those question link helped me solve the problem. :)

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.

Comment: How did you do it please?